# What are the differences between `ssh -R port:host:hostport` and `ssh -L port:host:hostport`?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I learned about using `ssh -L port:host:hostport` from DigitalOcean tutorials, and later saw the use of `ssh -R port:host:hostport` for Remote VSCode extension. I seem to be able to accomplish the same outcome with either `-R` or `-L`. How are they different from each other?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115897/103151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-R`

> Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the remote (server) host are to be forwarded to the local side.

`-L`

> Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the local (client) host are to be forwarded to the given host and port, or Unix socket, on the remote side.

Use `man ssh` to find more and compare flags descriptions. You can also find ssh manual at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ssh.1.html

Comment: Consider to add link to actual Ubuntu-related documentation (available in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ ), not OpenBSD's.

Comment: ok, here you go :)